# Dynamical %rowtype variables in plsql

Tags: dynamic, plsql, sql-types, rowtype

How to make dynamic %rowtype var's?

```
table_name varchar2 (300)
type varchar2_tab IS table of table_name%rowtype;
```

Comment: `%rowtype` is evaluated by the compiler, not the runtime engine.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use %rowtype on a variable. You must use an actual table name or a cursor. It is the same as specifying a record type with members corresponding to each of the table's columns.

```
customer customers%rowtype;
```

If all you want is a table of varchar2s, just do

```
type varchar2_tab is table of varchar2(32767);
```

Comment: Just a note: But you can make a %rowtype variable on a cursor.

Answer (score 1):

When Oracle see the first statement

```
table_name varchar2 (300);
```

It think that `table_name` is a variable of type `varchar2` and does not think as table.